# Add Amplify Auth triggers without going through all CLI steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I need to create a Custom Message lambda trigger but it appears that the only way to do so is to go through all the steps in updating the auth category. I don't want to mess up my user pool and auth settings.  How do I skip all steps except the lambda options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can always add a new function using `amplify add function` and then attach this function as a trigger on cognito user pool config screen.
downside is you will have to do this for all your user pools but it doesn't mess your amplify configurations.

[image: user pool config menu]

Comment: One thing to be aware of is if you choose to go this route your trigger assignments will be wiped out everytime you run amplify push. You will have to manually go into the triggers and assign the lambdas every time.

Comment: I think that happens when you redeploy everything to a new environment. I do amplify push all the time with a manual trigger like those and it doesn't wipe the trigger assignment

Comment: I have the same requirement and didn't create the trigger when I set up the amplify project. I can confirm that the custom triggers assigned manually get wiped out on every `amplify push`

Comment: Same for me, the custom triggers will wiped out on every `amplify push`